# Resulting quantiles from Quantile Regression DQN

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, probability-distribution, statistics, double-dqn

In my [QR-DQN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10044.pdf) application, the resulting quantiles for a state `s` and action `a` take the form of the blue line in the figure. The method works well in expected values and trains effectively. However, I know that in my problem the return distribution for `(s, a)` is multinomial with PMF only at `{-2, +2}`. Thus, I would expect the quantiles to take the form of the green line.

Is my expectation of the resulting quantiles correct? If yes, why does QR-DDQN behave this way?

[image]